# Accessing host machine from Minikube

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, minikube

I have a Google Cloud Datastore emulator running on my local machine at localhost:8742. I'd like to access this from a pod running in minikube. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the Google Cloud Datastore emulator by using the ip address for the host from the VM.  For the virtualbox driver (the default in minikube) this ip address is: 10.0.2.2

Comment: That worked however for future reference - is there a specific minikube command I can use to get this - I was hoping `minikube ip` may do it but I can't see the VM Ip

Answer (score 0):

[Telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io/) can do this and may prove generally useful to you for your k8s development work.

After installing Telepresence, and following the guide at [www.telepresence.io/tutorials/kubernetes-rapid](http://www.telepresence.io/tutorials/kubernetes-rapid), create a proxy service,

```
localhost$ telepresence --new-deployment some-name-you-like --expose 8742
```

Then, you can access the service `some-name-you-like` from the cluster as you might have done via `localhost`, for example via some shell or specialized data store client image,

```
kubectl --restart=Never run -i -t --image=alpine console /bin/sh
```